Android TV Now Playing Card, the "Open" button does not bring the activity in Android API 29 and above
I am able to get the activity pressing the Open button in API 28.
Also it works in Google TV (emulator) of any version, but no luck in Android TV 29 and above.
I use exoplayer 2.19.1
Creating the foregound service I declare a PlayerNotificationManager, a MediaSessionCompat, and MediaSessionConnector.
I have added the following:
notification_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Tv_Act_Player.class);
notification_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent pending_intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(),
                0,
                notification_intent,
                get_pending_intent_immutable_update_current(),
                getBackgroundActivityOptions()
        );
public static int get_pending_intent_immutable_update_current(String from) {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ? PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT : PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;
    }


public static Bundle getBackgroundActivityOptions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            return null;
        } else {
            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                options.setPendingIntentBackgroundActivityLaunchAllowed(true);
            } else {
                options.setPendingIntentBackgroundActivityStartMode(MODE_BACKGROUND_ACTIVITY_START_ALLOWED);
            }
            return options.toBundle();
        }
    }


In the manifest
<service
            android:name="RadioForegroundService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:permission="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true"
            />


<activity
            android:name="Tv_Act_Player"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize"
            />

